# Comments that end with inline code display a trailing dash

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

When a comment ends with `foo`, it will display with a trailing "–".

While it is easy to work around this bug by adding more text at the end, it would be great if it were fixed as this is very mystifying when first encountered.

Comment: a comment that ends with `foo`

Comment: the trailing - is just the separator between the comment and the username

Comment: @Marijin, @bobble: thanks! You are right, all comments end with  a "-" that separates the comment from the username, e.g. my original example: `(-)`

Comment: Re *"When a comment ends with `foo`, it will display with a trailing "–"."*. That is misleading. It always displays it.

Answer (score 6):

This is by design. All comments, when posted, have the same structure:

> content – username time

where "time" is either relative for recent comments or absolute for others. The " – " is to provide a bit of spacing between the comment's content and its meta-data (attribution and time).

If you end your comment's content with `foo`, therefore, it will look like

> blah blah blah `foo` – username time

which is by design.